# Python furl library - Is there a way to add a parameter to a url without url encoding it?

Tags: python

I have a url that I need to add an api key to as a parameter. The key has % and other characters in it and should not be url encoded, is there a way to do this with [furl](https://github.com/gruns/furl)?

Heres my current code:

```
request_url = furl('http://www.domain.com/service/') \
    .add({
    'format'     : 'json',
    'location'      : address_line_1 + ',' + city + ',' + state,
    'key'           : APP_KEY
}).url
```

Comment: But those characters _have_ to be URL-encoded if you want this to be a valid URL (and work). Imagine your API key is, say, `123%456%789`. If you just use `http://www.domain.com/service/?format=json&location=blah&key=123%456%789`, the server is going to see `key=123E6x9`.

Comment: You are probably not doing this correctly. The reason to use a URL library is so encoding is not something that you don't even technically have to be aware of.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow: To be fair, `furl` is designed to let you mix and match manually- and programmatically-created query strings (their first examples are about creating a URL from a string that already has `?one=1` on the end, and then adding `two=2` in various different ways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a url that I need to add an api key to as a parameter. The key has % and other characters in it and should not be url encoded

That can't be true. It *must* be URL-encoded. Otherwise, you end up with either an invalid URL, or a URL that doesn't mean what you wanted.

For example, let's say the key is `123%456%789`. If you send `http://www.domain.com/service/?format=json&key=123%25456%25789`, the web service on the other end will get `123%456%789`, which will succeed. If you just send `http://www.domain.com/service/?format=json&key=123%456%789`, the web service on the other end will get `123E6x9`, which will fail.

So, your example is already correct, and you shouldn't need to do anything.

If, for some reason, you're already URL-encoding `APP_KEY` before you get here… well, don't. With a name like that, I'm guessing it's a constant literal just copied and pasted into your module, which means you had to manually URL-encode it and copy and paste the result. Just don't do that, and you're fine.

If you got the `APP_KEY` in URL-encoded form, you can always decode it with, e.g., `urlparse.parse_qs`, or even with `furl`.

But if none of that seems reasonable…

> is there a way to do this with furl?

No. See the [Encoding](https://github.com/gruns/furl/blob/master/API.md#encoding) section of the docs. `furl` only works on *decoded* query string names and values.

But there's an easy way around this. A URL isn't that complicated of a thing, and `furl` is specifically designed to allow you to mix and match manually- and programmatically- created bits. Most of the examples in the [README](https://github.com/gruns/furl) show exactly that, such as `furl('http://www.google.com/?one=1').add({'two':2}).url`. So, if you've already got a pre-encoded `"key=123%25456%25789"` from somewhere, just stick it on the string manually before giving it to `furl`:

```
request_url = furl('http://www.domain.com/service/?key={}'.format(APP_KEY)) \
    .add({
    'format'     : 'json',
    'location'      : address_line_1 + ',' + city + ',' + state,
}).url
```

Hacky? Well, yes, in that you're side-stepping `furl`'s encoding, but that's exactly what you're asking how to do.

Comment: I was working with mapquest, it appears their api key comes url encoded. I've opted to decode it with urllib and then include it in the add function.

Comment: It looks like in their "Manage AppKeys" web page, they do show it pre-encoded. Which is silly. I think the cleanest thing to do is decode it in your interactive interpreter, then store the decoded version in your program instead, which is what it sounds like you've done. (I might add a comment explaining what it was decoded from and why.) But embedding it in the URL instead of using `furl` would probably also be reasonable.